# Base R or tidyverse function to expand rows along time series columns

Tags: sql, r, database, dataframe, dplyr

I have a time series data frame with two ID columns and about 1000 columns for day 1, day 2, etc.
I want to convert from my data frame being in the form

```
a    b    t1    t2  ... t1000
_____________________________
a1   b1   #     #       #
a2   b2   #     #       #
```

to being in the form

```
a    b    t    value
____________________
a1   b1   't1'     #  
a1   b1   't2'     #
a2   b2   't1'     #   
a2   b2   't2'     #
```

Essentially, I want to do something like this:

```
dataframe %>%
  select(starts_with("t_") ) %>%
  gather(key = "t", value = "value")
```

so that I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
t    value
__________
't1'   #
't2'   #
...
't100' #
```

for **each row** in the original dataframe. Then once I have the time columns that I generated from one row in the original dataframe, I want to left append the "a" and "b" columns to each row, so that this:

```
t    value
__________
't1'   #
't2'   #
...
't100' #
```

turns into this:

```
a    b    t    value
____________________
a1   b1   't1'   #
a1   b1   't2'   #
...
a1   b1   't100' #
```

and then I repeat this process for each row, stacking the new generated dataframe below (or above) the previously generated dataframe. At the end I want to have the dataframe in the code block above generated for each row of the original dataframe, and all stacked on top of one another. I could do this with a for loop, or maybe even some `sapply` magic, but I don't want to use a for loop in R, and I feel like there's a better way to do this than `sapply`-ing some function into each row of the original dataframe.

Can anyone help me? Thanks. Preferably using tidyverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)
data <- matrix(1:1000,nrow=2,ncol=1000)
colnames(data) <- paste0("t",1:1000)
data <- data.frame(a=c("a1","a2"),b=c("b1","b2"),data)
data[1:2,1:10]
#   a  b t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8
#1 a1 b1  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15
#2 a2 b2  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16


data %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("t"), names_to = "t")

## A tibble: 2,000 x 4
#   a     b     t     value
#   <fct> <fct> <chr> <int>
# 1 a1    b1    t1        1
# 2 a1    b1    t2        3
# 3 a1    b1    t3        5
# 4 a1    b1    t4        7
# 5 a1    b1    t5        9
# 6 a1    b1    t6       11
# 7 a1    b1    t7       13
# 8 a1    b1    t8       15
# 9 a1    b1    t9       17
#10 a1    b1    t10      19
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)    
dataframe %>%
     gather(key = "t", value = "value", 3:ncol(.))
```